# Util Class in Java

Tags: java, android

I want to know about the util Class used in Java. I am currently working on one Application in Android where I need to used a class from one file to another different file. I was told to import it like `import com.android.utli.(ClassName)` here the "com.android.util" is a package name.

Can I use that class in my another file simply by importing the package along with the class name?

Comment: Of course you can do that. Theses util classes exist to be reused in your own classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  After you import the class at the top of your java file like:

```
import android.util.Log;
```

You can then use it in your code.

```
Log.debug("MyActivity", "Thing I want to log");
```

Answer (score 2):

The package is really a part of the "fully qualified class name". You can actually use that fully qualified name everywhere you use the class name, e.g.

```
com.android.util.UtilClass myUtil = new com.android.util.UtilClass();
```

But that's rather inconvenient. Therefore, classes in the same package (and in the package `java.lang`) can be used shorthand (i.e. only the class name) without imports. Classes from other packages have to be imported before they can be used that way.

It's just a way to organize the code and prevent problems when different programmers write classes with the same name - as long as they are in different packages, the collision can always be resolved by using the fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA utitlity / Helper Class is here**

imports

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

class is here

```
public class Utils {
    /**
     * Convertim to time format
     *
     * @param unix is time with long value
     * @return string time
     */
    public static String convertUnix2Date(long unix) {
        if (unix == 0) return "";
        String result;
        Date date = new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(unix));
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        result = f.format(date);
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Handling the keyboard on device
     *
     * @param activity
     */
    private static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                        Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (activity.getCurrentFocus() != null && activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null) {
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                    activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handling the listener to dismiss the keyboard on device
     *
     * @param context <br>
     * @param view    is parent view <br>
     */
    public static void setupDismissKeyboardListener(Context context, View view) {

        // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
        if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
            view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                hideSoftKeyboard((Activity) context);
                return false;
            });
        }

        //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
                setupDismissKeyboardListener(context, innerView);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Converting the DP value to PX to display on device
     *
     * @param context <br>
     * @param value   is DP value
     * @return PX value
     */
    public static int parseFromDPtoPX(Context context, float value) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                value,
                resources.getDisplayMetrics()
        );
    }


    public static void setupUI(View view, final Activity activity) {
        //Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
        if(!(view instanceof EditText)) {
            view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
                hideSoftKeyboard(activity);
                return false;
            });
        }

        //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
                setupUI(innerView, activity);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     *
     */
    protected Utils() {

    }

    public static final String TAG = "Utils";
    public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
    private static String sFormatEmail = "^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$";

    /**
     * @return true if JellyBean or higher
     */
    public static boolean isJellyBeanOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if Ice Cream or higher
     */
    public static boolean isICSOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if HoneyComb or higher
     */
    public static boolean isHoneycombOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if GingerBreak or higher
     */
    public static boolean isGingerbreadOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if Froyo or higher
     */
    public static boolean isFroyoOrHigher() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO;
    }

    /**
     * Check SdCard
     *
     * @return true if External Strorage available
     */
    public static boolean isExtStorageAvailable() {
        return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
                .getExternalStorageState());
    }

    /**
     * Check internet
     *
     * @param context
     * @return true if Network connected
     */
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null) {
            return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check wifi
     *
     * @param context
     * @return true if Wifi connected
     */
    public static boolean isWifiConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifiNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiNetworkInfo != null) {
            return wifiNetworkInfo.isConnected();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check on/off gps
     *
     * @return true if GPS available
     */
    public static boolean checkAvailableGps(Context context) {
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        return manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    /**
     * Download data url
     *
     * @param urlString
     * @return InputStream
     * @throws IOException IOException
     */


    /**
     * @return an {@link HttpURLConnection} using sensible default settings for
     * mobile and taking care of buggy behavior prior to Froyo.
     * @throws IOException exception
     */
    public static HttpURLConnection buildHttpUrlConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        Utils.disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary();

        URL url = new URL(urlString);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        return conn;
    }

    /**
     * Prior to Android 2.2 (Froyo), {@link HttpURLConnection} had some
     * frustrating bugs. In particular, calling close() on a readable
     * InputStream could poison the connection pool. Work around this by
     * disabling connection pooling.
     */
    public static void disableConnectionReuseIfNecessary() {
        // HTTP connection reuse which was buggy pre-froyo
        if (!isFroyoOrHigher()) {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check an email is valid or not
     *
     * @param email the email need to check
     * @return {@code true} if valid, {@code false} if invalid
     */
    public static boolean isValidEmail(Context context, String email) {
        boolean result = false;
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(sFormatEmail);
        Matcher mt = pt.matcher(email);
        if (mt.matches()) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * A method to download json data from url
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ThrowFromFinallyBlock")
    public static String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        } finally {
            assert iStream != null;
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```